# Remove/add text based on user selection from drop drown w/ Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just need to add an asterisk to the end of some text based on a user's selection from a dropdown field. If the user select's option one from the drop down then the asterisk is attached and if the user selects the second option than the asterisk is removed. I think I need to do this with jquery but I am having trouble figuring out which function I should use. I tried to wrap the asterisk in a div and toggle the div's css display property with Jquery but this seems really clunky. Is there a better way to go about adding/removing text dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select>
    <option value="1">First option</option>
    <option value="2">Second option</option>
</select>
Some text <span id="asterisk" style="display:none">*</span>

$(document).ready(function() {

    // bind to the select's change event
    $("select").change(function() {
        if($(this).val() == "2") {
            $("#asterisk").hide();
        } else {
            $("#asterisk").show();
        }

    // fire the event once when the page loads
    // so the visible state of the asterisk is based on the selected option
    }).change(); 
});
```

Comment: @OP: In other words: The way you're doing it (showing/hiding an element) is perfectly reasonable (which is what my answer said, but karim's got here first, so I deleted it). :-)